# Group hash values -Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash, inject

Ok I'm having a little trouble wrapping my head around this solution. 
I initially was trying to make a word_counter hash that would have the number of occurrences as the key, and an array of all the words as the value.

My code was..

```
string = "hello hello hello hi hi to to a"

word_count = string.scan(/\w+/).each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |word,hash|
  hash[word.downcase] += 1
end

word_count = word_count.group_by {|k,v| v }
# => {3=>[["hello", 3]], 2=>[["hi", 2], ["to", 2]], 1=>[["a", 1]]}
```

So the main issue was that I did not want a 2d array as the value, and only wanted them to contain the words.

I ended up finding this solution

```
word_count.inject({}) {|h, (k,v)| h[v] ||= []; h[v] << k; h }
# => {3=>["hello"], 2=>["hi", "to"], 1=>["a"]}
```

This is exactly what I needed, but am not fully understanding how this works. Could someone please walk me through this ? Thanks!!

UPDATE: Thank you for the answers I really appreciate them! I have a much more thorough understanding of whats going on now.

Comment: Something wrong with your example, there is come from `a` ? `"hello hello hello hi hi to to"` not contain the char `"a"`.

Comment: Why don't you use `each_with_object` instead? That way you don't have to bother with the oft forgotten `; h` at the end of the block. Besides, you're not really injecting/reducing here as the feedback is artificial, you're really "iterating with baggage" and `each_with_object` exactly matches that intent.

Answer (score 4):

First, it may or may not help to know that [`Enumerable#inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) is also known as `reduce` because it takes a collection of values (hash or array) and "reduces" it to a single value. In this case, the result value is itself another collection, but it can be anything at all; the action and return type is determined by the initial value and block that you pass to `inject`.

Any time you might find yourself tempted to do something like this:

```
my_result = some_starter_value
some_collection.each do |item|
  my_result.incorporate( some_function_of(item) )
end
```

you're basically typing out the inject/reduce pattern in manual form. If you use `inject`, the above code becomes this:

```
my_result = some_collection.inject( some_starter_value ) do |so_far, item|
  so_far.incorporate( some_function_of(item) )
  so_far
end
```

In functional programming languages, this operation is called a "fold" - specifically, a "left fold".

The important thing to realize is that the value passed into the block as the "result so far" is *the return value of the last run of the block*. So the block must not only modify the result, but also return its new value. I like to use [`Object#tap`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-tap) to make that automatic:

```
my_result = some_collection.inject( some_starter_value ) do |so_far, item|
  so_far.tap { |sf| sf.incorporate( some_function_of(item) ) }
  # tap call returns so_far itself, no matter what the block returns
end
```

Anyway, on to your code:

```
word_count.inject({}) {|h, (k,v)| h[v] ||= []; h[v] << k; h }
```

You are running `inject` on a Hash, and passing in an empty Hash as the initial value.  So a manual version would look something like this:

```
my_result = {}
word_count.each do |key, value|
  my_result[value] ||= [] # if my_result[value] is nil, set it to empty array
  my_result[value] << key # append this key to the array
end
```

When you run `inject` over a hash, the block gets two values: the current result-so-far, and the current key/value pair as an array. So it looks like this:

```
 my_result = word_count.inject({}) do |new_hash, kvpair|
   key, value = kvpair
   new_hash[value] ||= []
   new_hash[value] << key
   new_hash  # remember to return new value from block
 end
```

but you can use destructuring to skip the separate key/value split-out step:

```
 my_result = word_count.inject({}) do |new_hash, (key, value)|
   new_hash[value] ||= []
   new_hash[value] << key
   new_hash  # remember to return new value from block
 end
```

Simplify the variable names to h, k, and v, and put it on one line with `{`...`}` in place of `do`...`end`, and that's your code.

As I said, I personally like to use `tap` instead of repeating the hash at the end. You can, if you like, also incorporate the initialization and the append into a single expression:

```
 my_result = word_count.inject({}) do |new_hash, (key, value)|
   new_hash.tap { |h| (h[value] ||= []) << key }
 end
```

but that arguably hurts readability. You could try to do what you did with the original hash and specify a default value in the constructor:

```
# Warning: does not work!
my_result = word_count.inject( Hash.new([]) ) do |new_hash, (key, value)|
  new_hash.tap { |h| h[value] << key }
end
```

But that doesn't actually have the desired effect, because each entry gets a reference to the same array and so winds up having exactly the same list of words. Instead you would need to do something like this:

```
my_result = word_count.inject( Hash.new {|h,k| h[k]=[]} ) do |new_hash, (key, value)|
  new_hash.tap { |h| h[value] << key }
end
```

... at which point it's no longer really an improvement over just doing the initialization inside the block.

Finally, this specific type of reduction, where each call to the block is getting as its "value so far" an unchanging reference to the same (mutable) object, is probably best modeled in Ruby by using [`Enumberable#each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) instead of `inject` - as you did when building the initial hash of word counts. Unlike `inject` (but similarly to `tap`), `each_with_object` doesn't care about the return value of the block; it always returns the same object you pass into it. Confusingly, while `inject` passes the previous block's return value as the first argument, `each_with_object` passes its object as the *last* argument (presumably in order to behave in a parallel manner to the similarly-named [`Enumerable#each_with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index)):

```
 my_result = word_count.each_with_object( {} ) do |(key, value), new_hash|
   (new_hash[value] ||= []) << key
 end
```

Comment: This is an awesome and well written explanation that makes perfect sense. Thank you for taking the time to write this out!!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
word_count.inject({}) { |h, (k,v)| h[v] ||= []; h[v] << k; h }
```

`inject` is a classic functional programming tool.

[image: inject, aka reduce, aka fold]

It takes an initial value (in the picture it this is called "z"), then applies all the values one by one to it, producing a new value that's going to be the initial value for the next round.

```
inject(initial) { |memo, obj| block } → obj
```

The documentation lists this example, which simply calculates the sum, perhaps it helps to understand the concept:

```
(5..10).inject { |sum, n| sum + n }            #=> 45
```

Explanation of the block:

```
{ |h, (k,v)| h[v] ||= []; h[v] << k; h }
   ^    ^        ^           ^       ^
   |    |        |           |     return the hash for the next round.
   |    |        |           add the element to the list
   |    |      create a new entry in the hash if it doesn't exist yet
   |   the next input, in this case, a key-value pair
  previous value of hash (in the first round this is the initial value)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are grouping key-values pairs from the hash. That's why you got arrays as `['hi', 2]`. To group only the keys by its values you have to get then first and use the value in the hash to group:

```
word_count.keys.group_by{ |k| word_count[k] }
# => {3=>["hello"], 2=>["hi", "to"]}
```

Comment: ahhhhh, I don't know why i didn't try this. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things here that deserve mention.

**Counting words**

Firstly, your regex should be `/\w+/`, not `/\w/`, but I expect that was a typo.

What you have is a more Ruby-like version of:

```
string = "hello hello hello hi hi to to"

arr = string.scan(/\w+/)
word_count = {}
count = 0
arr.each do |word|
  word_count[word] = 0 unless word_count.key?(word)
  word_count[word] += 1
end
word_count
  #=> {"hello"=>3, "hi"=>2, "to"=>2}
```

Substituting out `arr` saves one statement and using [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) eliminates two more:

```
count = 0
string.scan(/\w+/).each_with_object({}) do |word, word_count|
  word_count[word] = 0 unless word_count.key?(word)
  word_count[word] += 1
end
  #=> {"hello"=>3, "hi"=>2, "to"=>2}
```

`each_with_object` also has the advantage of keeping everything in its block away from prying eyes (by creating a new scope).

Defining `word_count` with a default of zero:

```
word_count = Hash.new(0)
```

means that if `word_count` does not have a key `word`:

```
word_count[word] #=> 0
```

It is important to understand that the above statement does *not* change the hash `word_count`. The statement:

```
word_count[word] += 1
```

expands to:

```
word_count[word] = word_count[word] + 1
```

which becomes:

```
word_count[word] = 0 + 1
```

if `word_count` does not have a key `word`. This is sometimes called a *counting hash*. So, one Ruby way is to write:

```
string.scan(/\w+/).each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) {|word, word_count| word_count[word] += 1}
  #=> {"hello"=>3, "hi"=>2, "to"=>2}
```

Since you want the count to be case-insensitive, you've converted `word` to lowercase. Let's also capture the result to a variable:

```
word_count = string.scan(/\w+/).each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |word, word_count|
  word_count[word.downcase] += 1
end

word_count
  #=> {"hello"=>3, "hi"=>2, "to"=>2}
```

Another way:

```
word_count = string.scan(/\w+/).each_with_object({}) do |word, word_count|
  word.downcase!
  word_count[word] = (word_count[word] || 0) + 1
end
  #=> {"hello"=>3, "hi"=>2, "to"=>2}
```

If `word_count` does not have a key `word`, the operative line becomes:

```
word_count[word] = (nil || 0) + 1 #=> 0 + 1
```

and one more:

```
word_count = string.scan(/\w+/).map(&:downcase).group_by(&:itself) 
  #=> {"hello"=>["hello", "hello", "hello"],
  #    "hi"=>["hi", "hi"],
  #    "to"=>["to", "to"]} 
word_count.update(word_count) { |*,arr| arr.size }
  #=> {"hello"=>3, "hi"=>2, "to"=>2}
```

This uses the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that employs a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged, which here is all keys. [Object#itself](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-itself) came with Ruby v2.2. For earlier versions, you need:

```
group_by { |word| word }
```

**Determining words with the same count**

Given `word_count`, your solution was:

```
count_to_words = word_count.group_by { |k,v| v }
  #=> {3=>[["hello", 3]], 2=>[["hi", 2], ["to", 2]], 1=>[["a", 1]]}
```

(which in v2.2+ you could write `word_count.group_by(&:itself)`.)

You are so close! Just one more step:

```
count_to_words.keys.each do |k|
  count_to_words[k] = count_to_words[k].map(&:first)
end
count_to_words
  #=> { 3=>["hello"], 2=>["hi", "to"] }
```

or (as I am reminded by @Mark):

```
count_to_words.tap do |h|
  h.keys.each { |k| h[k] = h[k].map(&:first) }
end
  #=> { 3=>["hello"], 2=>["hi", "to"] }
```

which we could combine with the calculation of `count_to_words` from `word_count`:

```
word_count.group_by { |k,v| v }.tap do |h|
  h.keys.each { |k| h[k] = h[k].map(&:first) }
end
  #=> { 3=>["hello"], 2=>["hi", "to"] }
```

or even substitute out `word_count` as well:

```
string.scan(/\w+/).each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |word, word_count|
  word_count[word] += 1
end.group_by { |k,v| v }.tap do |h|
  h.keys.each { |k| h[k] = h[k].map(&:first) }
end
  #=> { 3=>["hello"], 2=>["hi", "to"] }
```

One last way of modifying `count_to_words` (using `update`, as I did earlier):

```
count_to_words.update(count_to_words) { |*,arr| arr.map(&:first) }
  #=> { 3=>["hello"], 2=>["hi", "to"] }
```

One more thing. You had:

```
word_count = word_count.group_by { |k,v| v }
```

which reuses the variable `word_count`. Don't do that. `word_count` is now a misleading name for what you have and you've made debugging a pain, as you now have to remember to recompute `word_count` each time you run your code. In summary, **don't do that!**<sup>1</sup>

**What about [Enumerable#reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (aka `inject`)?**

`Enumerable#each_with_object` made its introduction in Ruby v1.9. Before that, Rubiests used `reduce` to accomplish what `each_with_object` does in a more direct way. (`reduce` remains extremely valuable, `arr.reduce(:+)` being a simple example). If you examine your completed solution with the one using `inject` that you found, you'll see that they are very similar. Two differences:

- `inject` here needs to return its "memo" for the next iteration; hence, that pesky `; h`; and
- the order of the block variables is reversed.

I explained `h[v] ||= []` in `h[v] ||= []; h[v] << k` earlier. (I prefer writing that `h[v] = (h[v]= []) << k`.)

<sub><sup>1 ...but it's OK for me to do that with update.</sup></sub>